# Get environment inside controller

Tags: ajax, testing, controller, symfony, phpunit

I have a situation in one of my controllers that should only be accessed via AJAX, I have the following code.

```
if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent('AJAX requests only!');
    return $response;
}
```

When I am testing this gives me an issue because the request hasn't actually been made via AJAX. This then breaks my tests every time. How should I go about working around this?

My Ideas:

1. I have tried to set a server header but have had absolutely no success.
2. Check if I am in the test environment in the controller and don't do the check if it is. I know this is dirty, but it would work. :-/ The problem was that I couldn't figure out how to discover what environment I am in.

Anyone else have any other ideas or tips that I am missing to get one of the above to work?

Comment: how did you set header in your tests?

Comment: See my comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the code for `isXmlHttpRequest` in class `Request` and method `getHeaders` in class `ServerBag`, the piece of code below should do the trick:

```
$client->request(
    'GET',
    '/path/to/test',
    array(),
    array(),
    array(
        'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
    )
);
```

I did not test it personally but I think it should works. The line of code below in `Request` is used to check if the http request is a `XmlHttpRequest`.

```
return 'XMLHttpRequest' == $this->headers->get('X-Requested-With');
```

In the code, `$this->headers` is set using:

```
$this->headers = new HeaderBag($this->server->getHeaders());
```

The method `getHeaders` creates an array of headers. Each server variable starting with `HTTP_`, plus some special server variables like `CONTENT_TYPE`, are put in this array.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: You hit the issue on the head. I was setting the header as `X-Requested-With` instead of with the `HTTP_` prefix. I thought I had tried that but...I guess not. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Of course in Icode4food's case, it's better to use Matt's solution, but here is how to find the current environment:

```
$this->container->getParameter(‘kernel.environment’)
```

Comment: shouldnt be $container->getParameter('kernel.environment');?

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike - yes, it has been changed. fixed.